# Detecting touch coordinate in UIImageView in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I need some help to achieve the following:

1. I want to make an application that shows human body images.
2. When the user taps on any of those images, it should show description of that body part, just like in any anatomy application of human body. For example, when the user clicks on parts or ears, it should show the description of ears.

   [image: img]
3. Also the user should be able to zoom-in those images.

If it is possible to achieve this, can anyone suggest me any resources or solutions to the problem or direct me in right direction?

Comment: Hi Ashish , have you done this? If Yes, Then Please let me know how we can do this.

Answer (score 0):

Just call this in the view controller that the UIView is a part of.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event { 
    CGPoint locationPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:yourImageView];
}
```

Comment: if i zoom imageview then locationPoint is change or not?

Comment: if you want to zoom, use a UIScrollView

Answer (score 0):

1) I think you should start solving this problem by implementing a **UITableView** or a **UICollectionView**. That way you can show images and description of human body. 
2) Then go for implementing the zoom-in image feature.

Refer  [Working with UITableView.](http://www.appcoda.com/uitableview-tutorial-storyboard-xcode5/)

You can also use UICollectionView here but I suggest learning to implement UITableView first as you said you are a newbie.

Comment: what you say how to imaplement it in Collection View?

Comment: well, here: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_7_Storyboard-based_Collection_View_Tutorial